# How can I get ffmpeg to stream my webcam?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to stream my webcam and managed to stream it successfully to bambuser.com using the following, but need to be able to view it locally.

This successfully posts it to babuser:

```
ffmpeg -v debug -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1,0 -acodec libmp3lame -itsoffset 00:00:00  
-f video4linux2 -s 360x240 -i /dev/video0 -r 15 -f flv -ar 44100 
rtmp://522f4133d0.fme.bambuser.com/b-fme/0bacf5bb634dbbbd52bdd99d71406dc6f362c
```

I've tried the following, but get "RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 111 (Connection refused) rtmp://localhost:8090/: Operation not permitted"

```
ffmpeg  -v debug  -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1,0 -acodec libmp3lame -itsoffset 00:00:00
-f video4linux2 -s 360x240 -i /dev/video0 -r 15 -f flv -ar 44100 
rtmp://localhost:8090/
```

How would I change this to be able to view it from localhost?

Answer (score 0):

with rtmp ffmpeg can only transmit to an "listening waiting rtmp receiver" (or possibly a http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/StreamingGuide#Pointtopointstreaming mentions a "listen" option for rtmp, maybe that can work.  Did you expected to have an rtmp server on localhost:8090 ?